# class not persisting new associated object when added to a set

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa, persistence

I am making a restaurant management app and I am having a problem persisting a user association. For the Chef class there is a set association with the Dish class so that specific dishes can be associated with a certain chef.

I have created a method that associates a dish with a chef, and when I try calling it on my REST client the method seems to work, and it returns a JSON of the chef object with the updated info, however when I call the get chef method the JSON no longer shows the added dish item

Here is the chef class and everything related to the Dish Object

```
@Table(name="chef")
public class Chef {

    //Chef Attributes
    @Id private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String address;
    private String bio;
    private Boolean delivery;
    private String photoURL;


    // @OneToOne
    // private ChefMenu menu;


    @Transient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chef", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("chef")
    private Set<Dish> menuItems;

    public Set<Dish> getMenuItems() {
        if (this.menuItems == null) {
            this.menuItems = new HashSet<Dish>();
        }
        return this.menuItems;
    }
```

Here is the Dish class with everything related to the Chef class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dish")
public class Dish {

    //Dish Attributes
    @Id private String dishName;
    private String cuisine;
    private double price;
    private String maxQuantity;
    private String dietaryRestriction;
    private String mealIngredients;
    private String cookingTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chef")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"menuItems","orders","firstName", "lastName", "email", "bio", "password", "address", "delivery", "photoURL"})
    private Chef chef;

public void setChef(Chef val) { this.chef = val; }

public Chef getChef() {
   return this.chef;
   }
```

Here is the method used to add a new dish to a chef from the repository

```
@Transactional
    public Chef addDishToMenu(Chef c, Dish d) {
        c.addDish(d);
        entityManager.merge(c);
        return c;
    }
```

And finally here is code from the controller class:

```
@PostMapping("dish/create/{dishName}/{cuisine}/{price}/{maxQuantity}/{dietaryRestriction}/{mealIngredients}/{cookingTime}")
    public ResponseEntity createDish(String username,
            @PathVariable("dishName") String dishName, @PathVariable("cuisine") String cuisine,
            @PathVariable("price") String price, @PathVariable("maxQuantity") String maxQuantity,
            @PathVariable("dietaryRestriction") String dietaryRestriction,
            @PathVariable("mealIngredients") String mealIngredients, @PathVariable("cookingTime") String cookingTime)
           {
        Dish d = new Dish();
        Double p = Double.parseDouble(price);
        //int mQ = Integer.parseInt(maxQuantity);

            try {
            d = foodRepository.createDish(dishName, cuisine, p, maxQuantity, dietaryRestriction,
                    mealIngredients, cookingTime);
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new Response(false, e.getMessage()));
        }

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(d);

     }



@PostMapping("dish/add/{username}/{dishName}")
     public ResponseEntity addDishToMenu(@PathVariable("username") String username, @PathVariable("dishName") String dishName) throws NullObjectException {
         Chef c = new Chef();
         Dish d = new Dish();
         c= chefRepository.getChef(username);
         d = foodRepository.getSpecificDish(dishName);
         c = foodRepository.addDishToMenu(c, d);
         return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(c);
     }

 @GetMapping("/get/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity getChef(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        // List<AppUser> user;
        Chef chef = new Chef();
        try {
            chef = chefRepository.getChef(username);
            // user = userRepository.getAppUserQuery(username);
        } catch (NullObjectException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new Response(false, e.getMessage()));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(chef);// user.get(0));

    }
```

So when I make the call on my Rest client to add a dish to a chef I get this as a response:

```
{
"username": "Favreau4",
"firstName": "Jon",
"lastName": "Favreau",
"email": "chefFavreau@email.com",
"password": "j+9UECq/PLA=$I+HsXngf/b82+rMtPQQO",
"address": null,
"bio": null,
"delivery": null,
"photoURL": null,
"menuItems": [
  {
"dishName": "Big sandwich",
"cuisine": "american",
"price": 5,
"maxQuantity": "3",
"dietaryRestriction": "bacon",
"mealIngredients": "bacon,lettuce,tomato,bread",
"cookingTime": "10mins"
}
],
"order": [],
}
```

but when I use the getChef REST call I get this:

```
{
"username": "Favreau4",
"firstName": "Jon",
"lastName": "Favreau",
"email": "chefFavreau@email.com",
"password": "j+9UECq/PLA=$I+HsXngf/b82+rMtPQQO",
"address": null,
"bio": null,
"delivery": null,
"photoURL": null,
"menuItems": [],
"order": [],
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of @Transient annotation? Transient are used to mark a variable as non-presistable. So your menuitems are not getting persist or saved in database.

Comment: Yes thank you I got rid of the transient annotation, and it started appearing, I think I had the wrong idea of what the @Transient annotation did. Thank you!